# Androidannotations RestErrorHandler not called in RestClient Robo Spice Request

Tags: android, android-annotations, robospice, spring-android

I configured the RestErrorHandler in my RestClient: restClient.setRestErrorHandler(restClientErrorHandler);

But it's not called.

I debugged the code and I see in the generated RestClient_ class that restTemplate.exchange is throwing an exception, but the try catch that calls my RestErrorHandler is being generated for response.getBody() and not the entire method.

Is this a bug in Androidannotations or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using my Androidannotations  RestClient inside a Robo Spice request.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a sample of Android annotations + RoboSpice somewhere ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a sample online. In general, I have a Bean class, ServerHelper, that I inject anywhere I want to perform a network request. In ServerHelper I inject the RestClient and in each RoboSpice request, in loadDataFromNetwork I call the RestClient method I need.

Comment: I am one of the maintainers of RS. If you get some time, we would appreciate an example. It could become part of RS and be added to our repo of samples.

Comment: @Snicolas sure I can do that. I love RS, I'd love to contribute if I can. How can we talk outside this question? :)

Comment: Via RS mailing list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an AA issue which has just been [fixed today](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/914) :)
You may use the SNAPSHOT until we release a new version.

Comment: Just checked it out today, and works great! Thanks! Sorry it took a while, I had a workaround working ;)